# Draw arrow according to path

Tags: android, android-canvas, android-touch-event

Currently I'm drawing a arrow head to my canvas by doing the following:

```
mPaint.setStyle(Style.FILL);

float deltaX = this.mPoints[1].x - this.mPoints[3].x;
float deltaY = this.mPoints[1].y - this.mPoints[3].y;
float frac = (float) 0.1;

float point_x_1 = this.mPoints[3].x + (1 - frac) * deltaX + frac * deltaY;
float point_y_1 = this.mPoints[3].y + (1 - frac) * deltaY - frac * deltaX;

float point_x_2 = this.mPoints[1].x;
float point_y_2 = this.mPoints[1].y;

float point_x_3 = this.mPoints[3].x + (1 - frac) * deltaX - frac * deltaY;
float point_y_3 = this.mPoints[3].y + (1 - frac) * deltaY + frac * deltaX;

Path path = new Path();
path.setFillType(Path.FillType.EVEN_ODD);

path.moveTo(point_x_1, point_y_1);
path.lineTo(point_x_2, point_y_2);
path.lineTo(point_x_3, point_y_3);
path.lineTo(point_x_1, point_y_1);
path.lineTo(point_x_1, point_y_1);
path.close();

canvas.drawPath(path, mPaint);
```

The above works fine. The problem I have is that the direction of the arrow is always pointing to the top right corner of my screen.

[image]

---

***MY QUESTION:***

How can I modify, what I already have, to draw the arrow in the direction of of my `onTouchEvent`?

---

It's also worth mentioning that I already get the direction in my `onTouchEvent` that I pass to my `onDraw` as shown below:

```
//Starting point X
float startX = mX; // MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN ---> mX = event.getX();
//Starting point Y
float startY = mY; // MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN ---> mY = event.getY();
//Move to X
float stopX = pX; // MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE ---> pX = event.getX();
//Move to Y
float stopY = pY; // MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE ---> pY = event.getY();
```

Using the above, when I draw a line, I would call:

```
canvas.drawLine(startX, startY, stopX, stopY, mPaint);
```

This will draw the line in the direction I want.
The problem is that `canvas.drawPath` takes 2 fields path and paint where `canvas.drawLine` takes 5 fields `startX, startY, stopX, stopY, paint`.

Any advise would greatly be appreciated.

Comment: simply calculate the angle for (startX, startY) (stopX, stopY) vector and rotate and translate the canvas before calling `Canvas#drawPath`

Comment: @pskink but what if I want to draw multiple shapes, the other shapes will be rotated with the canvas?

Comment: your question was: `"How can I modify, what I already have, to draw the arrow in the direction of of my onTouchEvent?"` wasnt it?

Comment: @pskink yes it was.

Comment: if you want to draw something else use `Canvas#save` / `Canvas#restore`

Comment: @pskink rotating the canvas didn't work, when I rotate the canvas the arrow is still pointing to the top right corner, but now it is at a different location on the screen.

Comment: `Canvas#rotate` method works just fine

Comment: @pskink rotating the canvas doesn't take in account where the arrow was originally drawn, causing the drawn object to be misplaced, sometimes off screen.

Comment: so draw it from (0, 0) origin - `path.moveTo(0, 0); ...`

Comment: @pskink Like I said in the question, I start drawing from `MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN` if I set `path.moveTo(0, 0);` it will still not be at the correct place.

Comment: did you see my first comment here? (`"... and rotate and translate the canvas before calling ..."`) - it means you have to rotate and **translate** the canvas

Comment: @pskink Can you please provide a answer?

Comment: path.movetTo(0,0); path.lineTo(50,0); canvas.rotate(10); canvas.translate(100, 200); canvas.drawPath(path, paint); - of course insted of one `lineTo` you have to use 3 lines to form the triangle

Comment: @pskink Thank you for your time. Unfortunately this will not work with what I'm trying to achieve. I would like to point the arrow in the direction that the user drag their finger. Doing it in this way I would have to find some way to rotate the arrow a certain amount to match the `onTouchEvent`, as my question states - `How can I modify, what I already have, to draw the arrow in the direction of of my onTouchEvent`. I asked a new question - https://stackoverflow.com/q/53513066/8199772

Comment: sorry i hae no time to write complete code in java: [here](https://pastebin.com/raw/93Jbh8aP) you have the working method written in dart for flutter app - here radians is angle of your line and dx and dy is your `onTouchEvent` x and y position - thats all

Comment: I will give it a try. Thank you very much for taking the time to reply.

Comment: https://pastebin.com/raw/S9L9SK8Z - it does not work well when fingers slows down but i wanted it to be simple and hope you will get the idea

Comment: Thank you very much