# PointF 90degrees from X

Tags: java, android, android-canvas

Yesterday I asked a question -  [Draw arrow according to path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53495688/draw-arrow-according-to-path)

In that question I explained that I want to draw a arrow head in the direction of my `onTouchEvent`. I got a answer in the comments saying I should rotate the canvas.

Last night I got a new idea and this is where this question comes in.

---

I get the `x` position/coordinate in `MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN` by calling `event.getX();` inside my `onTouchEvent`.

I would like to know if it is possible to get a point/coordinate 90 degrees from `x`?

Here is a demonstration to give move clarity:

```
                                      |
                                      |
                                      |
                                      |
                                      |
                                      |
point I want to get --> x1------------x
```

As shown above, `x1` is what I want to get.

---

Also worth mentioning, the following will not work because the `x` axis might be at a angle:

```
x1 = x - value
```

---

**EDIT:**

I think I made the question unclear, sorry about that.

I'm going to create a scenario to explain myself better

In my `onTouchEvent` inside `MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN` I set the starting `x` and `y`, lets call it `xdown` and `ydown`, by calling `event.getX()` and `event.getY()`.

Then inside `MotionEvent.ACTION_UP` I get the x and y, same as above, lets call it `xup` and `yup`.

I then get the center point, lets call it `centerx` and `centery`.

It will now look like this:

```
               xdown, ydown
              |
              |
              |
              |
              |
              |
              |centerx, centery
              |
              |
              |
              |
              |
              |
               xup, yup
```

Now I want to get the x and y 90 degrees from `centerx, centery`, lets say at a distance of 40.

Another demonstaraiton:

```
                              xdown, ydown
                             |
                             |
                             |
                             |
                             |
                             |
  nintyX,nintyY <------------|centerx, centery
                             |
                             |
                             |
                             |
                             |
                             |
                              xup, yup
```

Answer (score 1):

Seems you have some direction and want to get perpendicular direction.

Components of direction vectors are `(dx, dy)`

```
dx = centerx - xup
dy = centery - yup
```

then components of left (note - "leftness" depends on coordinates system handness!) perpendicular vector are

```
 px =  - dy
 py =   dx
```

(`px=dy` and `py=-dx` if direction is wrong for you)

To get a point `ninty` at distance D in needed direction, normalize vector and multiply its components by D

```
lenp = sqrt(px*px + py*py)  
upx = px / lenp
upy = py / lenp
nintyX = centerx + upx * D 
nintyY = centery + upy * D
```

Comment: Ok wow, thats confusing..Just to clarify, is `(dx, dy)` the `x` and `y` values I currently get from my `onTouchEvent`? Can you please also clarify `To get a point at distance D in needed deirection, normalize vector and multiply its components by D`?

Comment: dx, dy is difference of some point (unnamed point at the top of vertical line - touchevent? ) and current position (x at your picture). For example `dx = touch.x - current.x`. The second question depends on: do you need to place `x1` at specified distance or at the same distance as touch?

Comment: Yes `x` is touchevent coordinates.

Comment: And what is direction to specify perpendicular to?

Comment: OK, my answer is valid, I'll just correct names. Done

Comment: I tried this but I now get a different shape and it is not at the correct position. I will keep trying

Comment: But you still have some base point, dedicated direction and want to make perpendicular to it?